# WordPress User Post Products

Tags: plugins, e-commerce, membership

I want to build a website for a project with the following requirements:

1. Any user can register
2. They can post product by selecting a category, tags and uploading pictures
3. Users can comment on the products
4. Users can rate a product
5. Users can view all products they posted, edit or remove the product

Do you have an idea of a plugin or a set of plugins which I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

These four requirments comes right of the box with wordpress. You don't need any extra plugin for that.

1. **Any user can register** - Go to `General settings` page and enable `Anyone can register` option by checking checkbox available next to it.
2. **They can post product** - Assign them a role of author so that they can publish posts, do comments, upload media etc.
3. **Users can comments** - By default anyone can comment on posts (products),  From 'Discussion Settings' menu you can configure it such a way that only registered users can do comments.
4. **Users can view all products** - post author can edit their posts, comment on their post etc.

**For Ratings** - Take a look at [Wordpress Plugin Directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/), You'll find plenty of good rating plugins there.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the followings:

1. By default any user can register. Enable it in General-> Settings
2. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-user-frontend/
3. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/

Do you have any coding experiencie with wordpress? Im not sure if with just plugins you can achieve all your requirements

Comment: GD star rating is an awful plugin. Please look at the source and try it - it's defiantly nothin' I'd recommend.

Comment: Any good alternative to recommend?. I haven`t use many rating plugins

Comment: yeps, I love hooking wordpress but before doing so, I just wanted to know any available plugins

Answer (score 0):

**You can easily get it all with these plugins**

1.**WP User Frontend** - This is for user register & Login forms and user profile pages.

2.**WP User Frontend** - For product uploads.change Post type from Post to product.

3.User can comment of any post or products.

4.**WP Product Review Lite** - this was easy to make. it has more features for ratings.

5.**WooCommerce Booster** - After installing , go to settings and choose the "**User products**" module. this will give you a page with all your uploaded products for editting.